# Остыть и остынуть, простыть и простынуть: в чём разница?

Tags: глаголы, омонимы

Существуют семантически очень близкие пары глаголов:

> остыть — остынуть
>
> простыть — простынуть
>
> стыть — стынуть
>
> застыть — застынуть
>
> *и др.*

Формы прошедшего времени у них омонимичны.

Существует ли разница в выборе глагола из пары или они являются полными синонимами?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 2):

Более того, слова в этих парах семантически идентичны! Некоторые словари (см. Ефремова, Викисловарь) считают варианты с -ну- разговорными, но можете ссылаться на Малый академический словарь, где соответствующие глаголы вполне нейтральны.

Суффикс -ну- связан с указанием на вид глагола и некоторые побочные компоненты значения, которые, однако, в глаголах без -ну- и так выражены. Таким образом, указанный суффикс избыточен и не необходим, но и в его использовании нет «ничего криминального».

Можно послушать еще и подкаст с главредом «Грамоты.ру» Владимиром Пахомовым: http://radio7.podfm.ru/govorim-pravilno/459/.